Tomer Devorah: "Delighting in insults". Doesn't that ruin their purpose as yisurin?
According to the Ramak in Tomer Devorah 3, he recommends that a person who wants to achieve humility should hope for, and try to delight in insults. He gives the simple logic that, like all yisurin (suffering), they work very well to remove our arrogance, but at the same time, they are better than other forms of yisurin, because they don't diminish your strength, health, wealth etc. They are otherwise "harmless", and so are the "best" form of yisurin.
So he concludes that we should hope for insults, and delight in them.
My question is, if you delight in insults, doesn't that mean they are no longer difficult, and therefore are no longer yisurin at all? Therefore, every step we take towards not being bothered by insults, is a reduction in their effectiveness in removing arrogance?

Not at all. If it's an insult from a worthless person - it is meaningless. But when a good person insults - that could be mussar.

@YDJ I did not see that logic in Tomer Devorah. In fact, it seems like something that goes rather against it.

I saw something like that in Chovos Halevavos, when someone peed on a rabbi - he took  it with happiness as if his sins were forgiven. We have a different view of the world.

According to Chacham David Hanono on the Pele Yoetz, suffering is not a necessary aspect of yisurim. He claims that Hashem sends unpleasent situations for us to get kaparrah, but it's up to us to decide how to deal with those situations (and that the kaparrah still works either way). I suppose this is similar to wishing someone a tsom kal- we might have thought a hard fast would be more effective

@יהושעק that sounds v good

It reminds me of a very remarkable comment in Moreh Nevuchim. There the Rambam says that there are three types of suffering in the world. 1) Intrinsic from being physical, 2) What people inflict on each other, 3) What people do to themselves. - But the Rambam says that the first is trivial compared to the second, and both are trivial compared to the third. Most suffering is self-inflicted.

Given that, I wondered if the Rambam would assume that the main kaparah of embarrassment cannot be from the majority of the embarrassment which is after all completely self-inflicted.

I don’t think the purpose of yisurim is pain as much as ridding one of ego and physical desires and attachments. One way this can be achieved is by being shamed. One can either be painfully humbled by this, or delight in the opportunity to rise above his ego.

@Yø-cRo you are on to something there for sure. I just think that idea needs a little development and increased water-tightness.

"כל מי ששומע קללתו ושותק נקרא חסיד" - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Midrash_Tehillim.16.9 and https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.834.6

I think you answered your own question by "try to delight in insults", like enjoying the pain of working out - you do suffer during the action but fell the enjoyment when the stress passes.

@AlBerko I had that thought but I couldn't complete that thought to my own satisfaction. If you have completed it, feel free to answer

Unless you rewrite the question, I don't think it needs an answer. It happened to me several times, when I post a question and then realize there's not much of a mystery left.
